# PHP: clearstatcache() not working

Tags: php, file-exists

My workflow is pretty simple:

1. I delete a file
2. I call `clearstatcache()`
3. I save a new file
4. I call `clearstatcache()`

Still, at the end, `is_file()` returns `false` for a while before deciding to return `true` when i refresh 10sec later for example.

It looks like a cache problem, doesn't it?

Here's a piece of my code:

```
// step 1
$path = 'file_to_delete.jpg';
unlink($path);

// is_file($path) returns false here -- normal behavior
// step 2
clearstatcache();

// step 3 -- some stuff going on on an uploaded image, that leads to:
imagejpeg($imagetosave, $path, 80);

// step 4
clearstatcache();

// is_file() returns false, i have to wait a couple of seconds before it starts returning true
```

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

Given all the answers i had, the problem doesn't ***seem*** to come from `clearstatcache()`.

But should i add, when i overwrite the file (thus its *existing* status doesn't change), `is_file()` returns the good result. but when its *existing* status actually changes, the problem happens. It would be weird if the error didn't come from `clearstatcache()`, right? (or something related to this cache indeed)

Comment: Does `is_file()` return true in pre-1st step position? Please provide the complete sample we can run and see that issue happens

Comment: I'm not sure why that is... but note that the first call to `clearstatcache` is useless, as `unlink` automatically clears the cache.

Comment: my guess is you just have a programming error somewhere. simplify your script to the bare minimum needed to produce the issue, to help you debug.

Comment: Sounds like there is a write cache enabled with the disk.

Comment: @nico I do know that, but i expected adding it event hough it's not need would solve the issue :p

Comment: @hakre A write cache? Could you tell me more about that? Is it like a buffer before actually writing to the file system?

Comment: @zerkms I edited the question to answer yours

Comment: @Pioul, exactly. A write cache does exactly that. As you sage the file, check the return value of the privous function if it failed or not instead. Don't stress your filesystem too much with clearstatcache.

Comment: @hakre The weird thing is that i just run the script again while monitoring what was happening on the ftp (using Filezilla). After saving the new file, i can see it on the ftp, but `is_file` still returns false. Since i can see it instantly, there's no write cache, right? And your solution would work indeed, but it's a quick n' dirty fix :(

Comment: Surely, the OS file system caching must be transparent? It cannot and should not cause this sort of weirdness, or that would cause an outrageous number of programs to have problems. It's not an OS I'd want to use. I'd suggest reporting this as a PHP bug, for lack of any better ideas.

Comment: Check is your hard-disk mount as NFS. If so, you know what I mean

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @hakre, check the result of the create/delete.

It's not quick-and-dirty, even Rasmus himself [recommends it](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28790):

> [2011-03-31 08:34 UTC] rasmus@php.net
>
> You guys realize that the stat cache is per-request, right? You only
>   need to  clear the stat cache before a file_exists() call if you A.
>   did a stat for it, and  B. either created or deleted it on that
>   request. In which case you shouldn't need  to stat it again since the
>   success status of the create/delete will tell you  whether the file is
>   there or not. Perhaps for long-running daemons or something  this
>   becomes more of an issue, but for a typical web request the stat cache
>   typically saves you dozens of system calls.

If you really insist on using `clearstatcache()`, the only thing (other than write caching) coming to my mind is, that you mave have a very *huge* upload folder, containing thousands of files.

Having many, many files in a single folder will definitely slow down re-stating.

If so, try to reduce the number of files to gain stat performance, e.g. by creating multiple folders, one folder for each initial char of your upload filenames, like `upload/a/`, `upload/b/`, etc.

Comment: The thing is i simplified the scenario to make the question simple, but the real one involves different scripts doing different tasks (one the deleting, one the creating -called after).

Liek you said, and as the PHP doc states, if scripts are differents, the should be no cache problem.

but it appears i had one, so i tried to solve it with `clearstatcache()`, but the issue seems to come from a different location, maybe my dear hoster..

And to answer your last point, i'm in a dev env, working on a couple of files, so the problem doesnt come from here i guess :)

Thanks for your answer though!